# Неверная длина хеша BCrypt

Tags: криптография, хеширование, bcrypt

В 1 чудесный день я захотел реализовать алгоритм BCrypt на C#, и тут понеслась…

У меня есть чистый хеш, который мы получаем в результате 64 итераций в коне́чной функции.

<sub>Чистый хеш (в качестве ключа использовал строчку "hello")</sub>

```
$2y$12$oy0YCRJ7YJ7Topl/8FT/E..3hithmF9mZkNhoGUpfVEK4aQdXSXEW
└┬────┘└─────────────────┬──┘╘══════════════╤══════════════╛
 └ Информация о хеше     └ Соль             └ Чистый хеш
                                              ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

Но проблема не в нём, а в его рекодировании с Base64 в UTF-8. Дело в том, что он имеет размер в 24 байта, а его "символьное" представление на ⅓ больше, т. е. `24 ⋅ 4 ∶ 3 = 32` символа. Но если мы сгенерируем хеш, используя уже готовый генератор, то обнаружим, что размер нашего хеша в UTF-8 равен 31 символу. Куда подевался ещё 1 символ?

Comment: Хорошо бы было привести пример правильного и пока получаемого, просто построчно, по действиям. Код пока не нужен.

Comment: @Majestio я ничего не понял. "правильного и пока получаемого" – что? "Код пока не нужен" – что? "построчно" – что?

Comment: покажи строчку хэша, покажи ее рекодированную в UTF-8 побайтно, (а код С# не интересует пока).

Comment: Все же лучше на примерах спрашивать. Мол нужна "такая" строчка, а получается "вот такая", а вот так она у меня преобразовывалась (тут покажи промежуточные результаты).

Comment: @Majestio вы невнимательно читали вопрос. В теории, UTF-8 представление на ⅓ больше, т. е. 24 байта -> 32 символа. Но на практике 24 байта -> 31 символ. Куда делся ещё 1 байт?

Comment: @Majestio и использовал я не свой, я другой, написанный за меня, хешер, и он выдаёт 31 символ.

Comment: @Majestio мой как раз таки 32 выдаёт

Comment: Перевод одной кодировки в другую (например в UTF-8) - это совсем другая "песня". И если этим занимается "не твой хэшер", ну его нужно смотреть.

Comment: @Majestio причём тут сам хешер? в стандарте написано, что 31 символ под чистый хеш. так почему не 32, ведь столько должно быть для шифрования дефолтной строки.

Comment: Для представления одного символа в UTF-8 может быть использовано от 1 до 4 байт. В твоем 24 байтном хэше могут быть символы, которые кодируются в UTF-8 разным количеством байт. Поэтому я и просил изначальную строку привести, та которая 24 байта.

Comment: @Majestio ну дефолтная строка я же написал! `OrpheanBeholderScryDoubt`

Answer (score 1):

По-моему ларчик открывается просто:

1. Длина хэша 24 байта (бинарные естественно)
2. 24 байта в Base64 представляют собой 32 ASCII символа
3. 32 ASCII символа в UTF-8 имеет длину 32 символа

Теперь, если мы пропустим шаг №2 - то есть перекодировку 24 байт в Base64, а начнем кодировать его напрямую из бинарного хэша, то можем получить длину хэша в UTF-8 от 24 символов до 48 (смотря как карты лягут). Почему? Все очень просто - UTF-8 работает так:

- Если в байте старший бит пустой (то есть это ASCII символ - грубо говоря символ латинского алфавита), то байт записывается "as-is"
- Если старший бит не пустой, то байт представляется как 2 символа

Пример [вычисления длины здесь](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter)

То есть происходит следующее:

1. В варианте автора, сначала вычисляется хэш, потом хэш перекодируется в Base64, который далее в UTF-8 - что всегда дает 32 символа
2. В варианте встроенной функции, вычисляется хэш, который перекодируется в UTF-8 сразу. И если в хэше есть нелатинские символы, то длина хэша в UTF-8 представлении начинает скакать и рандомно может показывать величины от 24 от 48 символов (в примере ТС это 31 символов).

Comment: Вы ошиблись: в примере 31 символ, а не 31 байт. Я кодирую дефолтную 24-байтовую строку, т. е. `24 * 8 = 192` бит, `192 / 6 = 32` символа, а получается 31 символ. Конечно, если на вход подать 31-байтовую строку, то итоговый размер будет 31 байт ;)

Comment: Нет, я не ошибся. Под байт, я естественно имел ввиду символы. Прочтите еще раз внимательно....

Comment: Нет вы ошиблись. Вы отите перевести байты хеша в UTF-8 символ, но там может быть и 0, т. е. <NUL>, и <CR>, и <LF>, и т. д. Для этого и нужна Base64: любой набор байт в буквы-цифры-точка-слеш. Поэтому пропускать 2-й шаг равносильно самоубийству.

Comment: все правильно, но байты можно перевести в символы и минуя Base64, сразу из байтов в символы через UTF-8, тогда и получается что длина будет разная - я как раз об этом и говорю :) Перевод байтов на UTF-8 вполне легальная операция :)

Comment: `string yourText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(yourByteArray);`

Comment: Я это и мет ввиду, но зачем? Для преобразования хеша в письменный вид используется Base64. И да, я зн. что так можно) Но текст потенциально будет нечитабельным (и/или содержать нечитабельные символы).

Comment: В общем понятно. На ваш вопрос я ответил. Дальше без комментариев. Считаю для себя тему закрытой. Вопрос почему - уже не ко мне.